# How to decide if this should be split into 2 classes or kept in the same class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, design-patterns, class-design

I've got a page with a list of some items. Each item has got some properties: comments, images, a title, a comments form, and content. It seems simple enough to create a class called `item` which will represent a single item in the list.

However, I've also got an 'orphaned' item which is used for adding new items to the list. E.g, it has got all the same properties, textboxes, buttons, etc for adding images, writing the content, etc but its not stored in the db, and it has got a new 'add' button which saves it to db, and its then added to the list.

Should I still create just 1 class called `item` and just have a property called something like `isSaved` to determine whether to show the 'Add' button, whether to show the comment form for it, etc?

Or should I create 2 seperate classes, call one `newItem` and use it for the orphaned item, and another `savedItem` and use it for the items which are already in the db?

Also, this is in javascript so I don't think I can use much inheritance.

Comment: javascript can have inheritance pretty easily using prototypes or just jQuery extend. IMO you should separate the UI of your objects from their data. have a "class" for holding all of the data, and then bind the data to UI elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you subclass when behavior or properties need to change. If the only difference is whether the object is saved to the DB or not, most likely, that is not a candidate for a subclass. Adding a property such as `isSaved` would probably be the best bet. Unless, that is, the behavior of one is fundamentally different from the other when it is saved/unsaved.

Comment: What's different is also that if its unsaved, then it needs to show a textbox for entering the title/content, whereas if its saved, then it only shows the saved title/content and buttons for editing them which toggle the textboxes, and if its saved only then the comment form becomes visible. what would you suggest?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of environment this is being created in, but what you're describing is typically view code. My personal opinion (albeit one that many, many others share) is that MVC (Model-View-Controller) architecture (or some variation there of) is the proper methodology to build an application. If you keep that sort of separation of logic, then that code doesn't belong on your model anyways. Rather, the view would either show the form or show the content based on whether `isSaved` is true or false.

Comment: true, thanks, that was the answer, i'll just split it into two views and use `isSaved` to determine which view to show. cheers